# English word that uses the Hebrew ר sound?

Tags: pronunciation, hebrew

Is there an English word that makes the more guttural "Resh (ר)" sound found in Hebrew?

For example, even though the Hebrew letter Chet (ח) is not found in English, English speakers can be told the "ch" sound in "Bach" is how to pronounce the Hebrew letter.  In the same way, I am looking for a word that English speakers pronounce with the Hebrew letter Resh (ר).

English speakers seem to have a hard time hearing the difference between the letter "R" and "ר".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern Hebrew <ר> has a variety of realisations. [ʁ] (a voiced uvular fricative or approximant) is the most typical, but [ʀ] (a uvular trill), [r] (an alveolar trill), or [ɾ] (an alveolar tap) are also used depending on the background of the speaker (the latter two are particularly associated with Sephardim and Mizrakhim, and the other "guttural" reshim being associated with Ashkenazim)

The vast majority of English varieties lack most of these sounds (although [ɾ] is an intervocalic allophone of /t/ and /d/ in many American varieties, and [ʁ] is the usual pronunciation of English /r/ in places with the so-called Northumbrian burr), and so there is no native vocabulary which most English speakers will have any of these sounds in

English speakers are likely aware of the fact that French or German speakers typically pronounce their r's differently from English-speakers though, and the typical French and German pronunciation is [ʁ] (with [ʀ] also being used in some French varieties), the same as the typical "guttural" resh. As such your best bet at finding a touchstone for this sound that English speakers have a chance of knowing is going to be French or German

Comment: The majority of Englishes do have [ɾ] as an allophone of intervocalic /d t/, though of course not the others.

Comment: not sure if it's true that the majority do, but you are definitely right that many do. I'll edit to clarify

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard [ɣ] in Israeli Hebrew. As a native speaker it sounds comical to me, and not like a rhotic at all.

Comment: I do think it’s the majority, actually. It’s not only American dialects – tapped dentals are very common in British, Irish, Australian, New Zealand and South African English too. They’re less common in Scottish (but then many people there have [ɾ] as a common pronunciation of /r/), Caribbean and Estuary, but those are the only larger dialect areas I can think of where it’s not frequent. (My knowledge of Indian English isn’t sufficient to say much there, except many speakers of Indian English also have [ɾ] for /r/.)

Comment: It might be added that the uvular realisations are typical of varieties of (modern) Hebrew historically influenced by Yiddish.

Comment: @fdb the masoretes actually distinguish between two different realisations of resh, a front one (likely an alveolar trill or tap), and a guttural one, apparently pronounced in the same place as qaph. Whilst the modern guttural resh is often attributed to Yiddish influence (and it is largely associated with Ashkenazim), it is far from proven that it isn't in fact a retention of the Masoretic guttural resh

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet As a Brit, tapped dentals are not very common here at all, and are generally perceived as sounding American. You may be right about Australia, New Zealand, and South Africa though

Comment: @TKR yeah that surprised me too, I'd not heard of it being used, and for that was going from wikipedia. I know there is variation in Arabic varieties on the pronunciation of ghayn between [ɣ] and [ʁ] though so it wouldn't surprise me if some L1 Arabic speakers heard normative modern Hebrew [ʁ] as their ghayn and pronounced it [ɣ], in which case it might be associated with Palestinian Arab Hebrew specifically

Comment: @Tristan Even within England, tapped dentals are in more or less free variation with glottalisation for many speakers outside Estuary (and probably also excluding dialects with preglottalisation). My personal impression is that glottalisation is spreading due to Estuary influence at the expense of taps and unreduced /d t/, but I still hear taps quite frequently in contexts like “it’s a lot better than…” [ᶦsə ˈlɒʔ ˌbeɾən̩ːˈaʔ].

Comment: L1 Arabic speakers generally pronounce the Hebrew rhotic as a trill -- I've never heard [ɣ]. I suppose it's possible it exists, but I suspect Wiki is wrong; it's hard to tell [ɣ] and [ʁ] apart if your language doesn't have them. BTW for the Masoretic guttural resh did you mean "pronounced in the same place as kaph" or "qoph"? I'd have guessed that referred to a uvular trill as in some Arabic varieties.

Comment: I did mean qoph, not kaph, sorry for the typo. Could easily refer to a uvular trill instead of a fricative, I don't think they describe its manner of articulation at all

Comment: I've never been to Israel and have next to no experience hearing Modern Hebrew. The wikipedia page for resh doesn't lift the velar pronunciation. The Modern Hebrew Phonology page cites Nurit Dekel (2014) as the source for that pronunciation. Given the late date there I'd guess it's a recent and still marginal development so I'll remove it from the answer

Comment: Suppose the velar might be a fleeting Iranian influence, given Middle Persian *gwl* (gul) "rose" < OldP. \*vrda (*weird*! ). I've no geo-historic information to rest on, but imagine a relation due to a comparison from *resh* "head, beginning" (the interpretation for the letters origin) versus *rose-bud, bulb, flower*. I wouldn't say this if it weren't for this paranthetical: "attested only in Proto-Indo-Iranian \*Hwardʰ- (“to grow”))" [en. wt] concerning the root for a slightly better evidenced \*wr̥dʰo- (“sweetbriar”). Further cp. "wine", Proto-Kartvelian \*ɣwino-; waw, digamma, G, \*h2, etc.

Comment: "I've never heard [ɣ]" @TKR and I don't terminal consonant voicing because it's not in my dialect. Native speaker intuition doesn't count for much.